# oledb exception Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have filled a table in msaccess with the data from some web resource. metadata of  table in msaccess and my code is as

```
Dim Con1 As OleDbConnection = Nothing
Dim LastDateTimeOfRawNews As DateTime = Nothing
Private Function copyLatestNewstoNewsAndTemporary()
Con1 = DB_Manager.getConnection()
Con1.Open()
Dim SQL2 As String = ""
LastDateTimeOfRawNews = "#6/7/2013 4:36:46 PM#"
SQL2 = "insert into TemporaryNews(Title) SELECT Title FROM News where News.news_Date >='" + LastDateTimeOfRawNews + "'"
Dim objCmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL2, Con1)
objCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
Con1.Close()
End Function
```

metadata:

```
NewsId ->    AutoNumber
Title  ->    Text
news_Date    Date/Time         etc
```

I got {"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."} exception

```
exception full detail is as under

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
ErrorCode=-2147217913
Message=Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at WBand.frmMain.copyLatestNewstoNewsAndTemporary() in C:\Users\Khanz\Desktop\Latest news\Editing\WBand\Form1.vb:line 679
   at WBand.frmMain.Button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Khanz\Desktop\Latest news\Editing\WBand\Form1.vb:line 918
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at WBand.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Also please tell me that is there any difference between datetime type of msaccess and vb.net's datetime type.

Comment: You assigning string value to `LastDateTimeOfRawNews` and use it as string in your variable that holds SQL Query. Can you try defining it as `Dim LastDateTimeOfRawNews As String` in your code?

Comment: i am getting date and time from a function as under. . . while hardcoded value is just for testing, and founding same exception

Comment: Dim QueryOFLastRecordOFRawNews As String = "SELECT TOP 1 news_Date FROM News ORDER BY NewsId DESC"
    'Dim QueryOFLastRecordOFRawNews As String = "SELECT news_Date FROM News where news_Date =#6/7/2013 11:36:13 AM#"
    Dim Conn2 As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Private Function GetDateTimeOfLastNewsInRawNews(ByRef QueryOFLastRecordOFRawNews As String)

Comment: rest of code                                                                            Conn2 = DB_Manager.getConnection()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(QueryOFLastRecordOFRawNews, Conn2)
        Conn2.Open()
        LastDateTimeOfRawNews = Nothing
        LastDateTimeOfRawNews = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        Conn2.Close()
        'MessageBox.Show(LastDateTimeOfRawNews.ToString())

    End Function

Comment: When you're running that query directly in access - does it accept the date in the `#6/7/2013 4:36:46 PM#` format?

Comment: yep it does.i tried it in access it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to force the database to understand your string formatting of a date, you should try to use parameterized query and let the framework to figure out what is the correct way to pass a Date to your database

```
Private Sub copyLatestNewstoNewsAndTemporary()
    Dim SQL2 = "insert into TemporaryNews(Title) " & _
               "SELECT Title FROM News where News.news_Date >= ?"
    Using Con1 = DB_Manager.getConnection()
    Using objCmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL2, Con1)
        Con1.Open()
        Dim LastDateTimeOfRawNews = new DateTime(2013, 6,7, 16,36,46)
        objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", LastDateTimeOfRawNews)
        objCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Parameterized query avoid problems with formatting values (Dates, Strings, Decimals) and remove any chance of Sql Injection Attacks

Comment: perfect sir it works perfect for hard coded datetime. thank you very much. please do me a little more favor. . Dim LastDateTimeOfRawNews = new DateTime(2013, 6,7, 16,36,46) in this line date and time is hard coded.   while

Comment: It doesn't matter, If you read a DateTime you pass a DateTime, the problem arises when you try to pass a string in a format that should be interpreted as a DateTime. Don't do that and pass directly the date that you read